# How can I show an Image in the same frame of a video in OpenCV ( Python )?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to show a video on cv2 and when the video is over I want to show and image. Right now I have this code and it runs well.The video starts and when it's over a new frame it's opened to show the image.But what I want is the image to show on the same frame as the video when the video it's over. How can I achieve this?

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', -1)
if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening video stream or file")
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows();
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.imshow('image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show img in the same window, then pass in the same name:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', -1)
if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening video stream or file")

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

        # add waitKey for video to display
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
            # do not close window, you want to show the frame
            # cv2.destroyAllWindows();
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.imshow('Frame', img)   # note the difference
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks